# Create facebook open graph object

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to be able to programmatically create facebook open graph object so i can later perform actions on that object for example like or share

How can i do it programmatically? I have a facebook app (android platform) and i can see a list of generic actions on the dashboard but i want to be able to create programmatically objects and then use their ids for further actions

For example the create movie object code on the facebook developers site is:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();


GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
   AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
  "me/objects/video.movie",
  params,
  HttpMethod.POST
 );
 GraphResponse response = request.executeAndWait();
 // handle the response
```

Is that the way to create an object? what permission do i need for to create the object? o dont want anyone to be able to create objects

Any clarification will help